# Pandas performance: Multiple dtypes in one column or split into different dtypes?

Tags: python, pandas

I have huge pandas DataFrames I work with. 20mm rows, 30 columns. The rows have a lot of data, and each row has a "type" that uses certain columns. Because of this, I've currently designed the DataFrame to have some columns that are mixed dtypes for whichever 'type' the row is.

My question is, performance wise, should I split out mixed dtype columns into two separate columns or keep them as one? I'm running into problems getting some of these DataFrames to even save(to_pickle) and trying to be as efficient as possible.

The columns could be mixes of float/str, float/int, float/int/str as currently constructed.

Comment: you should ALWAYS split them out; mixed dtypes are the PRIMARY causes of slowness

Comment: How about for size constraints? I am running into size limits of some kind when trying to save. Would this increase size considerably?

Comment: I would NEVER save in pickle; use HDF5 (or even csv is better than pickle). You can chunk both the reads and writes.

Comment: pickle was able to save files that HDF5 wasn't in my last attempt. HDF5 was erroring out at 10mm rows.

Comment: its because you have mixed dtypes; always a VERY bad idea. I would fix that first. Any code you do will be orders of magnitude faster.

Comment: If you want something to be int32 versus the pandas int64 default, is there a better way to get the column to be int32 other than just casting as that type if you are getting the DataFrame from a .from_dict call?

Comment: no, no automatic way to do that (though you could write a function to take the max abs value of an int column and figure it out)

Comment: I just changed ~15 of the columns to the correct dtypes. I see it taking up the same amount of memory. Any reason for this?

Comment: If you're using nbytes you won't see a difference in the value because object float64 and int64 nbytes per element is the same. Do you mean taking up the Same amount of disk space?

Comment: That doesn't mean the total number of bytes is the same, object pointers are the same size as float64 on a 64 bit system

Comment: @PhillipCloud is right; I don't mean efficiency in memory space; but in computational efficiency. Having the correct dtypes is extremely important.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that it may depend on what your subsequent use case is. But IMHO I would make each column unique type otherwise functions such as group by with totals and other common Pandas functions simply won't work.